# a.exe has stopped working quicksort program

Tags: c, quicksort

I wrote the following implementation of the quicksort algorithm.I cannot guess why the following code snippet is not working(well compiling but not able to run at run time a.exe has stopped working).I will be happy if anyone of you could help me in this regard:

```
main( )
{
    int a[ ]={9,2,3,1,6,5,6,3,2,9,8,1,4,5,5,6,5,99};
    quicksort(a,0,17);
    print(a,18);
```

}

```
void print(int a[ ],int n)
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
} 

   void swap(int a[ ],int left,int right)
      {
        int t;
        t=a[left];
            a[left]=a[right];
            a[right]=t;
     }

   void quicksort(int a[ ],int left,int right)
   {
    int i,last;
        if ( left >= right)
            return;
    swap(a,left,(last+right)/2);
        last=left;
        for (i=last+1;i<=right;i++)
            if (a[i] < a[left])
                swap(a,++last,i);
        swap(a,left,last);
        quicksort(a,left,last-1);
        quicksort(a,last+1,right);
```

}

Comment: What precisely is it doing or not doing that's the problem?

Comment: Regarding your approach, I'd recommend you have a separate partitioning function that you call in your `quicksort` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is right here:

```
void quicksort(int a[ ],int left,int right)
{
    int i,last;
    if ( left >= right)
        return;
    swap(a,left,(last+right)/2);
                 ^^^^
```

`last` is not initialised and yet you are using it as an addition to `right`.

Did you mean `(left+right)/2` ?

Not only did my compiler warned me (always enable warnings) but I further used a debugger to double check it is indeed the case.

The compiler warning:

`23:22: warning: ‘last’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`

The debugger output:

```
Breakpoint 2, main () at quicksortbroken.c:37
37      int a[ ]={9,2,3,1,6,5,6,3,2,9,8,1,4,5,5,6,5,99};
(gdb) n // go to the next line
38      quicksort(a, 0, 17);
(gdb) s // step into the function
quicksort (a=0xbffff6d8, left=0, right=17) at quicksortbroken.c:21
21      if ( left >= right)
(gdb) n 
23      swap(a,left,(last+right)/2); // okay, let's examine the variable I suspect is problematic
(gdb) p last // print the value of last
$1 = 1872329 // Oh, oh, definitely not supposed to be this value
```

This is using GDB under Linux, not sure how you are compiling your code but I'm pretty sure Cygwin comes with a Windows port of GDB, Microsoft also have a debugger of their own. No excuses not to use one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your are missing a warning like 
`‘last’ may be used uninitialized in this function`

First use of `last` without its initialization is creating segmentation fault so your exe is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in this snippet.
One is the general coding rule that every variable should be initialized with a value or it might happen your variable may take garbage value and give unexpected output.Second there is issue in your algorithm. In the function quicksort where you are calling swap function the correct parameters to be passed are "swap(a,left,(**left**+right)/2);"

P.S. - do provide function prototypes also if working on a project else ignore this.